# How to embed Git and Gecko/Webkit in C#?

Tags: c#, git, mono, webkit, gecko

I need to embed Git and Gecko/WebKit in a C# application that should run cross-platform compliantly. Am I dreaming or is this possible to do without a lot of work?

I'm looking into Mono's WebBrowser support, but I'm wondering how often they update the Gecko/WebKit engine.

I'd also prefer to be able to embed Git. I could run Git commands via command line, but I'm afraid that C# limits me from having a Git implementation built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Git part of your question: [NGit](https://github.com/slluis/ngit), [GitSharp](http://eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)